# Permanently disabling Touchscreen in Fedora 35 (Wayland)

Tags: linux, fedora, touchscreen

The Touchscreen on my computer hasn't been working properly for years, and since I never use it I simply used to have it disabled permanently. But since the upgrade from Fedora 32 to Fedora 35, all the typical solutions to disable it no longer appear to work.

```
xinput disable #
```

gives me the output

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
```

Which I believe means that things are now running on Wayland and not on xorg anymore.

But how do I permanently disable the touchscreen in Fedora 35? There's still new system updates every day, with the touchscreen behaving unpredictably every time I turn it on. Going to an older kernel version sometimes helps, but after some updates I'm not even able to type in any commands in terminal. Having the touchscreen disabled automatically is required to not get my computer completely bricked with some bad luck.

Comment: If you can disable it at BIOS/UEFI that would be the preferred solution obviously. Other than that you may still use X.org (check for option at the login screen). I don't know how to do that in Wayland either.

Comment: The computer does not have touchscreen settings in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not blacklist it in /etc/modprobe.d/? As always, [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_module#Blacklisting) has guidance, but here's the (outdated?) [Fedora docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Installation_Guide/rescuemode_drivers-blacklisting.html). As long as you know the name of the relevant module, it's often just a case of sticking "blacklist [module-name]" in to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

Comment: What module would I have to blacklist?

Comment: @Yora You'd have to find it https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184877/342209

Comment: I'm not on Fedora 35 yet, but I see `hid_multitouch` is a loaded module.  If you blacklist a module, tell us what happens.  :-)

Comment: On my laptop, `hid_multitouch` was the touchpad